# How to separate the two pieces of the AC adapter for Samsung tab 2 7.0

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I am trying to separate the two parts of the Samsung tab 2 7.0 AC adapter, since I am traveling to a country with different outlets.

I have tried pulling them but nothing seems to work.

Do you know how they can be separated?

Comment: They might be undividable. But that shouldn't be a problem to you: why not simply obtaining some travel adapter?

Comment: To Close Voters: This does not meet the criteria for "Not Constructive". Further, it's about hardware specific to an Android device.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung *Power Supply Unit* (PSU) I have (same for: *Tab2 7.0*, *Tab2 10.1*, and *S3 Mini*) just requires a firm pressure, to remove the Australia/New Zealand angle-prong portion.

***Push the power-prong element away from the bottom (with CE notice) of PSU. There is no release or catch, to stop this action.***

[image: Samsung PSU, with US power-prong insert (separated)]

*(If this does not exactly match shape/appearance of **your** PSU, then disregard.)*

---

The alternative approach is to instead obtain a *Samsung 30-PIN to micro-USB* adapter. This allows you to use ANY standard phone PSU or PC (USB to micro-USB cable) to re-charge the battery.

[image: Samsung 30-pin to micro-USB adapter]

[ebay > Micro USB Female to 30pin for Samsung galaxy tab P1000 .. adapter](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Micro-USB-Female-to-30pin-for-samsung-galaxy-tab-P1000-7500-7510-7300-adapter-/261110110090?pt=AU_TabletAccessories&hash=item3ccb60178a)